# What are invalid expressions in bash Looping Constructs?

Tags: bash

I'm reading the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs)

There is some description for the *for* command:

> An alternate form of the for command is also supported:
>
> `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done`
>
> First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to the rules described below (see Shell Arithmetic). The arithmetic expression expr2 is then evaluated repeatedly until it evaluates to zero. Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero value, commands are executed and the arithmetic expression expr3 is evaluated. If any expression is omitted, it behaves as if it evaluates to 1. The return value is the exit status of the last command in commands that is executed, **or false if any of the expressions is invalid.**

How can I make an invalid expression which causes a `false` exit status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make an invalid expression?

An incomplete arithmetic expression such as `i +` is invalid, for example.

```
$ for ((i +; 0; 0)) do :; done
bash: ((: i +: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clear invalid and produce an error:

```
LANG=C
for ((i=0 ; i+0=0 ; i++ )) ; do echo "$i"; done
bash: i+0=0 : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=0 ")
```

a valid & surprising but not very well known one:

```
for ((;;)) ; do echo "Hi!"; sleep .1; done
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
[...]
```

Comment: I don't think "invalid" means "evaluating to false".

Comment: the 2 for loops are valid expressions.

Comment: Same as another answer, the exit status is `1` not `false`

Comment: 1 is false in bash. RTFM